# Dropdown menu items in appbar material ui - React

Tags: reactjs, navbar, appbar

I have added a Material UI open menu feature in a React app. However when you click the menu item in the app bar and the dropdown appears, it doesn't appear directly below the menu item. Not sure what im missing, I have included a snippet of the code below. Thanks

```
class Tester extends Component {


constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        placeholder: []
        
    }
    
}
openMenu(){
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        toggle: !this.state.toggle
    })
}




    return (
      <Link className={classes.tester}  onClick={() => 
       {this.openMenu(this.state.toggle)}}>
       Tester
        </Link>
        <Menu
        id="simple-menu"
                                
        open={this.state.toggle}
         onClose={() => {this.openMenu()}}>
                                        
        <MenuItem>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem >My account</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem >Logout</MenuItem>
        </Menu>
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu must have an anchor to be able to appear next to this anchor. The prop is called `anchorEl`.

You can follow the [example from Material-UI docs](https://material-ui.com/pt/components/menus/):

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';

export default function SimpleMenu() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button aria-controls="simple-menu" aria-haspopup="true" onClick={handleClick}>
        Open Menu
      </Button>
      <Menu
        id="simple-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: how to close when mouse leave?